# Extract Portion of File Name "MM-YYYY" in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

All the filenames are "OhioSalesRevenueData1-2015" for Ohio's January, 2015 data or "AlabamaSalesRevenueData12-2015" for Alabama's December, 2015 data.  I'm putting the corresponding month number in a column for a large number of spreadsheets in a macro.  Right now my macro is:

```
       Range("X2").Select
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
```

But this only works for January spreadsheets.  I need to replace the "1" to get the months for all months' spreadsheets.  Is there a way to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: Either use `Dir` or `FileSystemObject` methods to retrieve files and folders name. Then create a UDF (User Defined Function) to remove leading non-numerical strings. Or make use of `Split(filename,"RevenueData")(1)`. Many ways are available.

Comment: I would use regular expressions to extract the mm-yyyy portion.  How to integrate it with your code is not possible as you have provided neither code nor data examples in sufficient detail to reproduce your problem. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is exactly as you show, you can replace the "1" with the following:

```
IIf(Mid(FileName, Len(FileName) - 6, 2) Like "##", _
    Mid(FileName, Len(FileName) - 6, 2), _
    Mid(FileName, Len(FileName) - 5, 1))
```

Of course, you could use simple worksheet formulas also. With your Filename in `A1`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,LEN(A1)-6,2)),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-6,2),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-5,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to determine the month from a particular filename.

If so, assuming your filename is in a variable `f`, and all your filenames contain the words `RevenueData` (and that your path does **not** contain `RevenueData`), the following should work:

```
f = "abcdefRevenueData12-2015.xlsx" 'For demonstration purposes

If Mid(f, InStr(f, "RevenueData") + 12, 1) = "-" Then
    Range("X2").Value = CInt(Mid(f, InStr(f, "RevenueData") + 11, 1))
ElseIf Mid(f, InStr(f, "RevenueData") + 13, 1) = "-" Then
    Range("X2").Value = CInt(Mid(f, InStr(f, "RevenueData") + 11, 2))
Else
    MsgBox "Unrecognised filename - " & f
    End
End If
```